# How to dynamically fill an array of svgs using css

Tags: html, css, svg

I am trying to create a star rating UI using SVG and css. I am looking for a way to fill in a percentage of the total stars. However I can't seem to get it working. I have tried `background-blend-mode` and `mix-blend-mode` however no option seems to work. I also can't add the svgs as a background so I can't use `mask-image`.

```css
.slider-item__stars {
  margin: 0 0.5rem 0 0;
  position: relative;  
  color: black;
  width: 180px;
}

.slider-item__stars span svg {
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
}

.slider-item__stars__overlay {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider-item__stars">
        <span>
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor">
            <path d="M9.049 2.927c.3-.921 1.603-.921 1.902 0l1.07 3.292a1 1 0 00.95.69h3.462c.969 0 1.371 1.24.588 1.81l-2.8 2.034a1 1 0 00-.364 1.118l1.07 3.292c.3.921-.755 1.688-1.54 1.118l-2.8-2.034a1 1 0 00-1.175 0l-2.8 2.034c-.784.57-1.838-.197-1.539-1.118l1.07-3.292a1 1 0 00-.364-1.118L2.98 8.72c-.783-.57-.38-1.81.588-1.81h3.461a1 1 0 00.951-.69l1.07-3.292z" />
          </svg>
        </span>
        <span>
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor">
            <path d="M9.049 2.927c.3-.921 1.603-.921 1.902 0l1.07 3.292a1 1 0 00.95.69h3.462c.969 0 1.371 1.24.588 1.81l-2.8 2.034a1 1 0 00-.364 1.118l1.07 3.292c.3.921-.755 1.688-1.54 1.118l-2.8-2.034a1 1 0 00-1.175 0l-2.8 2.034c-.784.57-1.838-.197-1.539-1.118l1.07-3.292a1 1 0 00-.364-1.118L2.98 8.72c-.783-.57-.38-1.81.588-1.81h3.461a1 1 0 00.951-.69l1.07-3.292z" />
          </svg>
        </span>
        <span>
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor">
            <path d="M9.049 2.927c.3-.921 1.603-.921 1.902 0l1.07 3.292a1 1 0 00.95.69h3.462c.969 0 1.371 1.24.588 1.81l-2.8 2.034a1 1 0 00-.364 1.118l1.07 3.292c.3.921-.755 1.688-1.54 1.118l-2.8-2.034a1 1 0 00-1.175 0l-2.8 2.034c-.784.57-1.838-.197-1.539-1.118l1.07-3.292a1 1 0 00-.364-1.118L2.98 8.72c-.783-.57-.38-1.81.588-1.81h3.461a1 1 0 00.951-.69l1.07-3.292z" />
          </svg>
        </span>
        <span>
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor">
            <path d="M9.049 2.927c.3-.921 1.603-.921 1.902 0l1.07 3.292a1 1 0 00.95.69h3.462c.969 0 1.371 1.24.588 1.81l-2.8 2.034a1 1 0 00-.364 1.118l1.07 3.292c.3.921-.755 1.688-1.54 1.118l-2.8-2.034a1 1 0 00-1.175 0l-2.8 2.034c-.784.57-1.838-.197-1.539-1.118l1.07-3.292a1 1 0 00-.364-1.118L2.98 8.72c-.783-.57-.38-1.81.588-1.81h3.461a1 1 0 00.951-.69l1.07-3.292z" />
          </svg>
        </span>
        <span>
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor">
            <path d="M9.049 2.927c.3-.921 1.603-.921 1.902 0l1.07 3.292a1 1 0 00.95.69h3.462c.969 0 1.371 1.24.588 1.81l-2.8 2.034a1 1 0 00-.364 1.118l1.07 3.292c.3.921-.755 1.688-1.54 1.118l-2.8-2.034a1 1 0 00-1.175 0l-2.8 2.034c-.784.57-1.838-.197-1.539-1.118l1.07-3.292a1 1 0 00-.364-1.118L2.98 8.72c-.783-.57-.38-1.81.588-1.81h3.461a1 1 0 00.951-.69l1.07-3.292z" />
          </svg>
        </span>
        <div class="slider-item__stars__overlay" style="width: 45%"></div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Would you be able to provide an example using my example html / css in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you looking for something like that ?

```js
// code used for demo the variation of the percentage of visible stars 
 
const percentElm = document.querySelector('div.slider-item__stars') 

inSiz.value = parseInt( getComputedStyle(percentElm).getPropertyValue('--percent') ) 
inSiz.nextSibling.textContent = ` ${inSiz.value}%`
//percentElm.style.setProperty('--percent', `${inSiz.value}%`)

inSiz.oninput=_=>
  {
  inSiz.nextSibling.textContent = ` ${inSiz.value}%`
  percentElm.style.setProperty('--percent', `${inSiz.value}%`)
  }
```

```css
.noDisplay  {
  display : none; 
  }
div.slider-item__stars {
  --percent  : 70%;
  font-size  : 0;
  width      : 10rem;
  background : #254253;
  }
div.slider-item__stars div {
  width       : var(--percent);
  overflow    : hidden;
  height      : 2rem;
  white-space : nowrap;
  }
div.slider-item__stars svg {
  display    : inline-block;
  width      : 2rem;
  height     : 2rem;
  fill       : yellow;
  }
```

```html
<svg class="noDisplay" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <symbol id="star-svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
      <path d="M9.049 2.927c.3-.921 1.603-.921 1.902 0l1.07 3.292a1 1 0 00.95.69h3.462
              c.969 0 1.371 1.24.588 1.81l-2.8 2.034a1 1 0 00-.364 1.118l1.07 3.292
              c.3.921-.755 1.688-1.54 1.118l-2.8-2.034a1 1 0 00-1.175 0l-2.8 2.034
              c-.784.57-1.838-.197-1.539-1.118l1.07-3.292a1 1 0 00-.364-1.118L2.98 8.72
              c-.783-.57-.38-1.81.588-1.81h3.461a1 1 0 00.951-.69l1.07-3.292z" />
    </symbol>
  </defs>
</svg>

<div class="slider-item__stars">
  <div>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 20 20"> <use xlink:href="#star-svg" x="0" y="0" /> </svg>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 20 20"> <use xlink:href="#star-svg" x="0" y="0" /> </svg>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 20 20"> <use xlink:href="#star-svg" x="0" y="0" /> </svg>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 20 20"> <use xlink:href="#star-svg" x="0" y="0" /> </svg>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 20 20"> <use xlink:href="#star-svg" x="0" y="0" /> </svg>
  </div>
</div>
<br><br><br><br>
<hr>
<p> Simple cursor for demo on the variation of the percentage of visible stars  </p>

<input id="inSiz" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" ><span> xx%</span>
```

You can also do that:

```js
// code for demo
const percentElm = document.querySelector('div.slider-item__stars svg') 

inSiz.value = parseInt( getComputedStyle(percentElm).getPropertyValue('--percent') ) 
inSiz.nextSibling.textContent = ` ${inSiz.value}%`
//percentElm.style.setProperty('--percent', `${inSiz.value}%`)

inSiz.oninput=_=>
  {
  inSiz.nextSibling.textContent = ` ${inSiz.value}%`
  percentElm.style.setProperty('--percent', `${inSiz.value}%`)
  }
```

```css
.noDisplay  {
  display : none; 
  }
div.slider-item__stars {
  width      : 10rem;
  height     : 2rem;
  background : #254253;
  }
div.slider-item__stars svg {
  --percent  : 50%;
  width      : 10rem;
  height     : 2rem;
  fill       : yellow;
  clip-path  : polygon(0 0, var(--percent) 0, var(--percent) 100%, 0 100%);
  }
```

```html
<svg class="noDisplay" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <symbol id="star-svg">
      <path d="M9.049 2.927c.3-.921 1.603-.921 1.902 0l1.07 3.292a1 1 0 00.95.69h3.462
              c.969 0 1.371 1.24.588 1.81l-2.8 2.034a1 1 0 00-.364 1.118l1.07 3.292
              c.3.921-.755 1.688-1.54 1.118l-2.8-2.034a1 1 0 00-1.175 0l-2.8 2.034
              c-.784.57-1.838-.197-1.539-1.118l1.07-3.292a1 1 0 00-.364-1.118L2.98 8.72
              c-.783-.57-.38-1.81.588-1.81h3.461a1 1 0 00.951-.69l1.07-3.292z" />
    </symbol>
  </defs>
</svg>

<div class="slider-item__stars">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 20" >
    <use x="0"  y="0" xlink:href="#star-svg" /> 
    <use x="20" y="0" xlink:href="#star-svg" /> 
    <use x="40" y="0" xlink:href="#star-svg" /> 
    <use x="60" y="0" xlink:href="#star-svg" /> 
    <use x="80" y="0" xlink:href="#star-svg" /> 
  </svg>
</div>
<br>

<div class="slider-item__stars">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 20" style="--percent:45%;">
    <use x="0" y="0" xlink:href="#star-svg"></use> 
    <use x="20" y="0" xlink:href="#star-svg"></use> 
    <use x="40" y="0" xlink:href="#star-svg"></use> 
    <use x="60" y="0" xlink:href="#star-svg"></use> 
    <use x="80" y="0" xlink:href="#star-svg"></use> 
  </svg>
</div>


<!-- demo part -->
<br>
<hr>
<p> Simple cursor for demo on the variation of the percentage of visible stars 
  <br> (first one only)
  <br> <input id="inSiz" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" ><span> xx%</span>
</p>
```

Comment: Your first suggestion worked a treat, thank you!